# Injecting code into a prototype object

Tags: javascript, url, prototype, new-operator, addeventlistener

I hope i'm clear. I would like to inject code into a prototype object( new instances of a user-defined object in a constructor) These are the objects in the code:

```
`var menu = new Menu("#myMenu");
var item1 = new Item("list");
var item2 = new Item("torso", "#FF5C5C");
var item3 = new Item("blind", "#FF5C5C");
var item4 = new Item("paypal", "#FFF15C");
var item5 = new Item("link", "#64F592");
var item6 = new Item("blind", "#FF5C5C");`
```

Essentially i want these new variables `var item1` to `var item6` of the `class Item {
constructor(icon, backgroundColor)`to each link to a url or div when clicked.
so i would like to know how do i inject a code example and `addEventListener` to each of this var objects so that they each perform their own function, where do i actually fit the code to do this.  I tried this in the constructor:

```
this.$element.on('click', function() {
window.location.href = "book.html"; 
});
```

but this only works for the `var menu`.